# Why can I directly test an interface against a value?

Tags: go, interface

To my surprise, this compiled (and ran) fine with Go 1.13:

```
var v interface{}
if v == "" { // false
    fmt.Println("v is empty string")
}
```

I was always under the impression I need to do type switches and/or assertion before I can such test. And poking it a bit more on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/51bZxTETEDh):

```
v = 0
if v == 0 { // True
    fmt.Println("v is 0")
}
type myType struct {
    a string
    b int
}
v = myType{}
// Only works if myType is comparable
if v == (myType{}) { // true
    fmt.Println("v is empty myType")
}
```

Can somebody tell me why this is legal? Is it safe to rely on this behavior? For example, if I want to test if a variable is an empty string, zero integer or float:

```
func isZero(v interface{}) bool {
    return v == "" || v == 0 || v == 0.0
}
```

Would this get me in trouble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) says this of comparison operators:

> In any comparison, the first operand must be assignable to the type of the second operand, or vice versa.
>
> The equality operators == and != apply to operands that are comparable. The ordering operators <, <=, >, and >= apply to operands that are ordered. These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:
>
> - A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.

(I've trimmed away all the other bullet points; follow the link for the full list.)

Your `v` has type `interface{}`, so the first questions to ask are:

- Does any `x` implement the empty interface?  (Yes, it does.)
- Is `x` itself comparable?  (It is for string and int.)

Then, if the comparison is allowed, the code compiles; so at runtime we ask:

- Does `v` hold `x`'s dynamic type?  If so, is its dynamic value equal?

If both are true, `x` equals `v`; otherwise `x` is not equal to `v`.

> (your code sample)
>
> ```
> func isZero(v interface{}) bool {
>     return v == "" || v == 0 || v == 0.0
> }
> ```

If `v` holds `float32` or `int64` or some other reasonable type, we might be in a bit of trouble.

Answer (score 5):

The [specification explains](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) why the comparisons are legal:

> A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.

This statement applies to the example in the question because all types implement the interface `interface{}`.